# My decorator does not work when I run the program

Tags: module, generator, decorator, yield

I am programming a machine that gives shifts for meat, fish and fruit in a supermarket. I have 2 modules, numbers.py and main. In numeros.py is the code of a function decorator and three generators. In principal.py is where are the functions that manage the program.

I run the program and when I select one of the areas (meat, fish or fruit) the corresponding turn appears but not the wrapper I want to give it.

How can I do so that the wrapper is shown on the screen together with the shift?

`**numeros.py**`

```
# Decorator

def decorador(funcion):
    def envoltorio_funcion():
        print('Su turno es: ')
        resultado = funcion()
        print('Aguarde y será atendido.')
        return resultado

    return envoltorio_funcion

# Generators

# Generador de turnos de carne

@decorador
def generador_carne():
    num = 1
    while True:
    yield f'C-{num}'
    num += 1

generador_carne = generador_carne()

# Genenrador de turnos de pescado

def generador_pescado():
    num = 1
    while True:
    yield f'P-{num}'
    num += 1

generador_pescado = generador_pescado()

# Generador de turnos de fruta

def generador_fruta():
    num = 1
    while True:
    yield f'F-{num}'
    num += 1

generador_fruta = generador_fruta()
```

`**principal.py**`

```
# Módulo de funciones que administran el funcionamiento del programa

# Importar el contenido de numeros.py para poder disponer de sus funciones

import numeros
from os import system

# Preguntar al cliente a qué área desea dirigirse

def menu():
    opcion = int(input('¿Para qué área desea sacar su turno?\\n'
                       '\[1\] - Carne\\n'
                       '\[2\] - Pescado\\n'
                       '\[3\] - Fruta\\n'
                       'Por favor, introduzca su respuesta: '))
    # Dar un número de turno según el área al que se dirija
    if opcion == 1:
        print(next(numeros.generador_carne))
    elif opcion == 2:
        print(next(numeros.generador_pescado))
    elif opcion == 3:
        print(next(numeros.generador_fruta))

# Invocar a la función menu

menu()

# Preguntar al cliente si desea sacar otro turno y repetir el proceso

otro_turno = input('¿Desea sacar otro turno? \[S/N\]')

# Mientras que la respuesta sea Sí debe de continuar ejecutándose el menú

while otro_turno.lower() == 's':
    # Limpiar la consola
    system('cls')
    # Invocar la función menu
    menu()
    # Preguntar al cliente si desea sacar otro turno
    otro_turno = input('¿Desea sacar otro turno? \[S/N\]')
```